# Get category if used in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, terms, meta-query, tax-query

I'm trying to get a list of categories if they are used in a Custom Post type. The post type uses the default categories taxonomy. There are also other custom post types that use the same default WP category.

Is it possible to add a meta_query that checks if the category is used in a Custom post_type? eq: custom post type: work.

```
$work_categorys = get_terms(
 [ 
   'taxonomy' => "category", 
   'hide_empty' => true,
 ]
);

foreach ($work_categorys as $key => $value) { echo '<li data-filter-tag="'.$value->slug.'" class="">'.$value->name.'</li>'; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This would work.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#comment-2500) As posted by [@bucketpress](https://profiles.wordpress.org/bucketpress/).

```
$someposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'work',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids', // return an array of ids
    )
);

$somepoststerms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'object_ids' => $someposts,
        'hide_empty' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: This worked when I removed the tax_query from $someposts query. If I left it in it returned an empty array. What does that part try to do?

Comment: Good question, I've tested it too, but doesn't seem necessary for your purposed. I've updates the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

To get all terms from all taxonomies assigned to "work" custom post type you can customize your code to look like this

```
$taxes = array_keys( get_object_taxonomies( 'work', 'objects' ) );
$work_categorys = get_terms(
 [ 
   'taxonomy' => $taxes, 
   'hide_empty' => true,
 ]
);
```

Comment: I get an error: `WP_Error Object Invalid taxonomy.` Wouldn't this just return the taxonomies used in a custom post type? not the actual categories eq(name, slug, id...)?

Comment: Yes, the get_object_taxonomies() will return taxonomies assigned to a custom post type, the result you can use in the get_terms() call which will return an array of WP_Term objects, although i am looking your original post again and it seems this might not be what you are looking for after all :/